# How to apply LVM properly to a server already with multiple partitions?

Tags: partition, lvm

My question is, what if a server I were going to administer had their own partitions, such as one for /usr, /var, /home, /tmp and root - How would I handle them after utilizing LVM?:

Lets say I create physical volumes out of each of them, then create logical volumes, mount the PV's and copy their contents to the LV's, what would I do with the old physical volumes left over? It just seems odd to leave sda2,3,4,5 separate partitions if they are not actually going to be utilized separately, just utilized globally by LVM.

Is it normal to leave them be (seems a bit messy)? Should I use pvmove and delete them, and make the whole disk one physical partition? How would this normally be handled?

Answer (score 1):

In order to reuse existing partitions, you just need to change their partition-type to 0x8e, the Linux LVM type, and then add them to a Disk Group.

If you have the option, copying all the data off and reformatting is better, though. Fewer PVs to muck about with simplifies things for LVM.